# $(f(c)-f(a))(f(b)-f(c))<0$ prove that there exists a $d$ such that $f'(d)=0$.

Tags: calculus

I have a homework question which is:

> If $f : [a,b]->R$ is continuous in $[a,b]$ and differentiable at
>   $(a,b)$ and exists a point $c$ in $(a,b)$ such that
>   $(f(c)-f(a))(f(b)-f(c))<0$ then prove that there is a point $d$ in
>   $(a,b)$ such that $f'(d)=0$.

I am having trouble proving this - I am sure I am missing some simple algebra trick to show that $\frac {f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=0$ or something like that...

Can someone help me please?

Thanks :)

Comment: Well, what do you have so far?

Comment: Well visually it's clear right? $\Delta_{ac}:=f(a)-f(c)$ is the difference of the function values $f(x)$ between the start point and the mid point. $\Delta_{bc}:=f(b)-f(c)$ is the difference of the function values between the end point and the mid point. The condition is $\Delta_{ac}\Delta_{bc}>0$, i.e. both differences have the same sign, i.e. the function somewhere forms a hill or a pit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By hypothesis, $f(c)-f(a)$ and $f(b)-f(c)$ must have different signs. So either

1) $f(c)>f(a)$ and $f(b)<f(c)$.

or

2) $f(c)<f(a)$ and $f(b)>f(c)$.

Suppose case 1) holds. Choose any number $r\ne f(c)$ between $f(c)$ and $\max\{f(a),f(b)\}$.

Then on the interval $[a,c]$, we have $f(a)\le r< f(c)$. By the Intermediate Value Theorem, there is a point $d$ in $[a,c]$ with $f(d)=r$.  Since $r\ne f(c)$, it follows that $d\in  [a,c)$.

On the interval $[c,b]$, we have $f(b)\le r<f(c)$. By the Intermediate Value Theorem, there is a point $e$ in $[c,b]$ with $f(e)=r$. Since $r\ne f(c)$, it follows that $e\in (c,b]$.

Thus we have points $d\ne e$ in $[a,b]$ with $f(d)=f(e)$.
The Mean Value Theorem then gives a point $h\in(a,b)$ with 
$$f'(h)=
{f(e)-f(d)\over e-d}=
0.$$

I'll leave case 2) for you.

---

In Case 1:

[image]

the graph of $f$ intersects the line $y=r$ in each of the intervals $[a,c)$ and $(c,b]$.

Comment: Hmm seems simple - but I am not sure I understand how you get the points d and e. Can you please elaborate on that some more? Thanks :)

Comment: @Jason I just added the detail in my answer.

Comment: Great Answer :) Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Define $\ g(x):= (f(x)−f(a))(f(b)−f(x))$
Clearly g is continuos on $\ [a,b]$  and differentiable (a,b). Note that $\ g(a)=g(b)=0$. By weierstrass g attains its minimum value on the compact interval $\ [a,b]$. Now note that g(c)<0 some c in $\ (a,b) $. By that and the fact that g is zero on the endpoints of the interval it follows that $\ g'(d)=0$ some d in (a,b). But $\ g'(d)=f'(d)(f(a)+f(b)−2f(d))$. But now it follows that either f'(d)=0 in which case we are done, or $\ f(d)=(f(a)+f(b))/2$. But  $\ f(d)=f(a)+f(b)/2$ is false since if it was true then  $\ g(d)=(f(b)-f(a))^2$ Contradicting that $d \in (a,b) $ is the minimum value attained by  $\ g(x).$

Answer (score 0):

$(f(c)-f(a))(f(b)-f(c))<0\implies 2 case f(c)>f(a) and f(b)<f(c) or f(a)>f(c) and f(b)>f(c)$
From both cases,it is easy to use MVT to show the slope of the function f(x) consist of positive and negative and we can concluded that by contiunity,there must exist a number d st $f'(d)=0$

Comment: This is only true if $f'(x)$ is continuous no? Or am I making a mistake?

Comment: $f'(x) must be continuous