# $(f(c) - f(a))(f(b)-f(c)) < 0$ show that there exists a t such that $f'(t) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

If we have a function f which is continuous and differentiable on $[a,b]$ and $(a,b)$ respectively. It is given that there exists a $c$ in $(a,b)$ such that
$$(f(c) - f(a))(f(b)-f(c)) < 0$$
We have to show that there is a $t\in(a,b)$ such that $f'(t) = 0$.

My thoughts so far:
We have a case where $f(c)-f(a)$ is negative meaning $f(b)-f(c)$ is positive. This means $f(c) < f(a)$ and $f(c)>f(b)$. But this doesn't seem to imply that there is a turning point, so I'm stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If $f(b)-f(c)>0$ then $f(c)<f(b)$. You wrote that this implies $f(c)>f(b)$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving a point exists on a differentiable function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98721/proving-a-point-exists-on-a-differentiable-function) (new title : $(f(c)-f(a))(f(b)-f(c))<0$ prove that there exists a $d$ such that $f'(d)=0$.)

Comment: Thank you both. This should answer my question